# Python - Trying to get a different timezone

Tags: python, timezone

Totally new to python, I'm actually working on an ex-colleague's script. in looking at it it seems fairly straight-forward. Here's the situation:

The script looks at current localtime (UTC) and renders a time-based table that scrolls/changes throughout the day as the hours pass so there's always a rolling 8 hour table.

The problem is that now we'd like to deploy a copy of this tool (on the same server) in CST ('America/Chicago') (meaning I need to change the UTC time to CST) so I'm just trying to find a way to modify what he has to make the 'current_time' variable == GMT -6.

He used strftime() to get the first hour:

```
current_time = int(strftime("%H"))
if current_time <19:
temp_page.write(...)
elif current_time == 19:
temp_page.write(...)
```

etc.

So - from my php knowledge, I'd love to be able to do something like:

```
current_time = int(strftime("%H"), (localtime() -6 hours))
```

(yes, I realize that's not real php code, but hopefully you get my meaning ;-))

In my research, I've come across pytz, but this is not installed on the webserver, though I can probably get it if that's the best/easiest way too implement it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably use the [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) module (it's part of the standard library, so it's installed if a standard python is on the system).

In particular, datetime objects can have an optional [`tzinfo`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.tzinfo) attribute, used during timezone conversions. [Here](http://agiliq.com/blog/2009/02/understanding-datetime-tzinfo-timedelta-amp-timezo/)'s a blog post that explains step-by-step how to use those.

Comment: Thanks Mac, this is what I was looking for! I might start using pytz because it looks like it's got some good things, but my code is now:
`code` current_time = datetime.now()-timedelta(hours=6)
current_time = int(current_time.strftime("%H"))

Comment: Thanks @eumiro - that's even easier!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, try to install `pytz`, it will help you a lot when working with different timezones (and UTC).

The current UTC time (independent from the timezone of your computer) can be obtained with:

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now(pytz.utc)
```

`now` is now `datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 30, 14, 26, 30, 628014, tzinfo=<UTC>)` and you can use it to calculate the current UTC hour with `now.hour` (returns `14`)

Comment: I'll add pytz and begin working with it, but for the quick fix I went with the datetime example. Thanks a lot!